# Setting Styles for an Array of Labels - Flash Builder 4.6

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, apache-flex, styles, label

Having a bit of trouble setting label colors in a for loop

This works as expected:

```
label1.styleName = "myStyle";
```

However this does not:

```
for (var j:int = 0; j < labels.length; j++) {
    labels[j].styleName = "myStyle";
}
```

When I trace the style I get the style name, but nothing changes visually, as it does in the first example.

I've tried other things such as:

```
(labels[j] as Label).setStyle('color', 0xFFFFFF); // Null object reference
```

And all the variants I could think of on that....setStyle(), as LabelItemRenderer...

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, for anyone else who happens to have this unusual problem, I had added the elements to the array wrong....

I had added them all in a loop without referencing with the 'this' keyword.... Nothing wrong with the code above, just the array. Derp!